# I want to write a code in vba with would split the arrays in a cell to multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data-validation

I am trying to split data from a single cell to multiple rows as shown below.

[image: [Top one is before and the bottom one is after]

I am using the below mentioned code:

```
Sub TransposeRange()

Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "Splitcell"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection.Range("A1")
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range(single cell) :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Arr = VBA.Split(InputRng.Range("A1").Value, Chr(9))
OutRng.Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you tried inserting an image then we cannot see it. What is your actual problem, what exactly is not working? What does the code fail to do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your input cell has horizontal tabs.  Your code:

```
Sub TransposeRange()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range

    xTitleId = "Splitcell"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection.Range("A1")
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range(single cell) :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    Arr = VBA.Split(InputRng.Range("A1").Value, Chr(9))
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
End Sub
```

Typical result:

[image]

Comment: You are right in that `chr(9)` is a tab, and the split doesn't split when there are no tabs in the input. I think the OP's image suggests the actual charachter to split on would be `chr(10)` or `chr(13)`